# Wildfly - can persistence.xml have a direct jdbc connection?

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, wildfly

or will wildfly always look for a `<jta-data-source>`?

when/where is the right place to use `javax.persistence.jdbc.*` properties to configure database access?

Answer (score 0):

Enterprise Application Servers like WildFly use JTA exclusively because that's what the Java EE Transaction Management standard demands for those.

Resource local transactions are meant for manual JDBC connection handling and the purpose of an AS is to have it manage resources on your behalf.

So, you shouldn't use resource local transactions in WildFly or any other AS. You need to use the JTA DataSource the container already provides you.

Comment: "Resource local transactions are meant for manual JDBC connection handling" doesn't seems to be right statement. Resource local transaction means there is only single resource (database). In majority of the cases, you have only one transactional resource, however it does not mean that there has to be manual jdbc connection handling. For e.g., you can use third party connection-pool ( like tomcat jdbc pool or c3po). Also you can have JTA datasource with single resource. The transaction manager does optimizations for single resource where 2 phase commit is not required.

Comment: How do you think the transaction is managed if not through java.sql.Connection.commit() and java.sql.Connection.rollback()? That's why it's bound to a single connection, as you or some other framework you rely one has to call these methods for setting the transaction boundaries. For JTA it's the XAConnection that's being used.

Comment: You are right but the point I am trying to make is that JTA is an API and XA comes into picture when there are more than one resource and one of them is XA resource. You can use JTA with single resource ( resource local).

Comment: Yes, you are right. Resource local is for one DataSource while JTA is for at least one.

Comment: In theory, if I'm doing integration testing, can I use a non-JTA data source in a Wildfly web container?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22827485/in-jboss-wildfly-should-i-enable-jta-on-data-source-to-use-with-jpa  Experiences mentioned here suggests it's better to use the jta enabled. There is no harm in using JTA enabled datasouce.