# Services with missing/unavailable dependencies error

Tags: java, jboss7.x, ear

Trying to start a bean on JBoss AS 7 got this error:

```
15:55:51,252 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "dodsr.ear" was rolled back with failure message {"JBAS014771: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.persistenceunit.\"dodsr.ear/dodsr.jar#DoDSRMGR\"jboss.naming.context.java.DoDSRDSMissing[jboss.persistenceunit.\"dodsr.ear/dodsr.jar#DoDSRMGR\"jboss.naming.context.java.DoDSRDS]"]}
```

Can someone please explain what this means?  What do I have to configure to get this thing to run?

Also, this line in the log:

```
15:55:51,287 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS014774: Service status report JBAS014775:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
  service jboss.naming.context.java.DoDSRDS (missing) dependents: [service jboss.persistenceunit."dodsr.ear/dodsr.jar#DoDSRMGR"]
```

What is this trying to tell me that I have done wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following your last question, I can guess the problem is that in your persistence.xml file you are referring to a JTA Data Source named `java:/DoDSRDS`.

The server logs are telling you that it doesn't have a JDBC Datasource with that name. Check in your Jboss admin console in the JDBC Data Sources section to see if your resurce's name is correct. You should have a JDBC Data Source named `DoDSRDS`.

Also, You are using the format `java:/DoDSRDS`. I don't have much knowledge about Jboss resource naming but after reading [other related posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16897063/configuring-ejb-on-jboss-as-7-using-jta-datasources-every-statement-is-commited) I think the correct format for your resource name should be `java:jboss/DoDSRDS`. Try using this format in the persistence.xml file and see if it works.

Comment: Also, be sure that you check the "Use JTA" option in the Jboss Admin Console / JDBC Datasource.

Comment: Thank you for the input, I appreciate it.  Made some changes per your advice and am now getting this error: 
     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: JBAS011470: Persistence unitName was not specified and there are 2 persistence unit definitions in application deployment "dodsr.ear".  Either change the application to have only one persistence unit definition or specify the unitName for each reference to a persistence unit.
Does this mean that there are two persistence.xml files in the archive?

Comment: Yep. The deployment manager found two persistence.xml files in your EAR check your project.

Comment: Where should the file be?  In the META-INF of the ear or the jar?

Comment: It can be in either of those places but not in both.

Comment: Thank you but it failed again with this message:
09:34:51,879 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "dodsr.ear" was rolled back with failure message {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.subunit.\"dodsr.ear\".\"dodsr.jar\".DEPENDENCIES" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit.\"dodsr.ear\".\"dodsr.jar\".DEPENDENCIES: Failed to process phase DEPENDENCIES of subdeployment \"dodsr.jar\" of deployment \"dodsr.ear\""}}

Comment: 10:19:42,073 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS015871: Deploy of deployment "dodsr.ear" was rolled back with no failure message

JBAS014775:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
      service jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.datasources.DoDSRDS (missing) dependents: [service jboss.persistenceunit."dodsr.ear/dodsr.jar#DoDSRMGR"]

Comment: It looks like you haven't created the DoDSRDS dataSource yet, or it has another reference name. Check [this article](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_BRMS_Platform/5/html/BRMS_Administrator_Guide/Configuring_a_Datasource_for_JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform_6.html) about how to configure a JNDI dataSource for Hibernate/JPA in your JBoss server.

Comment: this is for JBoss AS 7, would that make a difference?