# Rollback of transactions with java ee and Jboss AS

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss

I have a stateless bean, that has container for transaction management, and i have 2 separate for loops in what i add some data to the database, and in other i delete some data.
After that, i run some validity check, and if it fails, i throw an exception.
What is not clear to me is, if an error is thrown, why is transaction not rolled back? I tried throwing a custom exception at first, then a RollbackException, but the result is the same - rollback is not done.
Is it possible that Jboss is overriding some of mine settings, or am I missing out on some other part?

Also, i was wondering what is considered "a transaction" in stateless bean, that is container managed? Is it everything inside a method, or could one method contain more than one transaction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JBoss has some dreadful default in the Datasouce configuration. Datasources created in JBoss are not JTA - in admin console the Use JTA setting is unchecked and in xml related setting is `<datasource jta="false" ...`. Check if changing it to `jta="true"`, will not solve your issue.

Check this [Transactions don't rollback](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26319117/3701228) for some more details.

Comment: This looks like a possible solution, but i won't have time to test it before tomorrow :) I will let you know if it helps

Answer (score 1):

> if an error is thrown, why is transaction not rolled back?

Because that is what the specification says. Any `RuntimeException`s or checked exceptions marked with `@ApplicationException` are rolled back.

> Also, i was wondering what is considered "a transaction" in stateless bean, that is container managed? Is it everything inside a method, or could one method contain more than one transaction?

All EJB methods per default join a transaction. If none is available a new one is created. You can have more than one transaction when you call an EJB method with `REQUIRES_NEW`. Just remember this will be an independent transaction, not a subtransaction.
See `@TransactionAttribute` for more information.